# Tomcat does not uses my application's log4j.properties

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat8

My web application runs on Tomcat 8.0.36. However, the application's log4j.properties does not seem to get picked up by Tomcat. This file is at

```
/WEB-INF/lib
```

and

```
/WEB-INF/classes
```

I did quite Google, but I am not able to find out a solution. How can I fix this?

If Tomcat uses another one instead of my application's log4j.properties, how can I find out which one Tomcat uses? Can I instruct Tomcat to use mine?

My web application uses log4j 1.2.17, which I do not plan to change.

Comment: try to use PropertyConfigurator.configure("configFilename")

Comment: have you looked at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j ?

Comment: svarog, I got it working already. Thanks for chiming in! I looked at that link before my post.

Comment: How did you get it working?